# How to join KStream and a lookup table (GlobalKTable) on regex / pattern matching?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

My goal is to have a stream of data (KStream) that has Integer as its ID , and a String as its value, and for this example, we'll be storing someone's name in the value. And then I will also be creating a lookup table using GlobalKTable that stores terms as its keys (Terms that will be matched with the stream's value) and a boolean flag (Indicates that any name that matches this term is a 'spammer') as the value.

My first question on this regard is if it is possible to join KStream with GlobalKTable on regex / pattern matching rather than a strict match.

If not, is there a better design consideration that I can consider to achieve the same goal ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`KStream#join(GlobalKTable)`](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#join-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.GlobalKTable-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KeyValueMapper-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.ValueJoiner-) to provide a `KeyValueMapper` that maps items in your `KStream` to items in your `GlobalKTable`.
In this `KeyValueMapper` you can match by regex or however you please.